# j2me polish text field

Tags: java-me, j2mepolish

I have a form with TextField.
When TextField accept DECIMAL value the form put 123 at the upper left corner.
When TextField accept alphabet the form put "abc" at the upper left corner when I run emulator.[image: problem with numeric "123" when textfield accept DECIMAL].[image: problem with "abc"]

(I have notified it with red circle)
It create some problem as unnecessary data.
Could any one please answer me how I can remove this "123" or "abc" from upper left corner of form.

Answer (score 0):

### i was found answer in j2me-polish documentation

> **Deactivate Input Indicator**
>
> The info item can be deactivated globally by setting the
> "polish.TextField.showInputInfo" variable to "false":
>
> ```
> <variable name="polish.TextField.showInputInfo" value="false" />
> ```

Visit http://www.enough.de/products/j2me-polish/documentation/lush-ui/visual-guide/gui-item-textfield.html#textfield-deactivate